# GSAP scaleX appearing out of sequence in timeline

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am new to GSAP and am putting together a 2.5D rotating coin using GSAP `scaleX` and `x`.

The coin is meant to a) "rotate" in the tails side, then b) rotate out the tails side, then c) rotate in the heads side, then d) rotate out the heads side, and then the loop of the sequence begins the rotate in of the tails side again.

I have gotten the animation as far as c), but when I try to use `scaleX` to start d), something happens to the timeline and the "heads" side of the coin appears from the very start of the animation.

I have included a codepen here: https://codepen.io/bamartelly/pen/RgayML

If you un-comment lines 103 to 108 (pasted in below too) you can see the animation breaking when I try to start implementing step d).

```
      .fromTo(coin.heads, flipTime,{
        scaleX:1,
        x:0
      } , {
        scaleX:0,
        x:8
      }, "headEnd")
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I suspect it's an immediateRender thing - please see https://greensock.com/immediateRender. Try setting immediateRender:false on that fromTo() tween. Does that help? You'll have a much better chance of getting an answer if you post in the forums at https://greensock.com/forums/

Comment: adding `immediateRender:false` as an option in the `toVars` worked thanks tons! Can you please submit it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's an immediateRender thing - please see http://greensock.com/immediateRender. Try setting immediateRender:false on that fromTo() tween.

Happy tweening!